# Reach the following equality between the heat flux and temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, conservation-laws

Does anyone know how to prove the following equality,

$\frac{\operatorname{Div}q}{\theta} = \operatorname{Div}(\frac{q}{\theta}) + \frac{q.\nabla\theta}{\theta^2}$,

where $\operatorname{Div}$ represents the divergence function, $q$ is the heat flux and $\theta$ is the temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1D it is very simple. Saying that the function $f(x)$ is defined as,

$f(x) = \frac{q}{\theta}$,

Then, the derivative of $f(x)$ is obtained, using the quotient rule, as,

$f'(x) = \displaystyle \frac{\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} \theta - \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}q}{\theta^2} \qquad \text{with} \qquad f'(x)=\displaystyle \frac{\partial q/\theta}{\partial x}$.

Applying some mathematical operations, then we will have,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\theta}\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=\displaystyle \frac{\partial q/\theta}{\partial x} + \displaystyle \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \frac{q }{\theta^2}$,

which can be easily extended to 3D case.

Answer (score 2):

It's strictly mathematical, obtained by applying the quotient rule for differentiation to the first term on the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: The 1-D version is $$\frac{\partial (q_x/\theta)}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{\theta}\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x}-\frac{q_x}{\theta^2}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$$